# Wordpress If Category statement then show this layered image

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, categories, custom-post-type

I have a wordpress blog that has a custom post-type with its own set of categories. There's a similar code in my template that uses a function that searches for different post formats in the blog section and show specific icons for that specific format. 
Ex: if(has_post_format('audio')) {return 'ICON IMAGE';}

I would like to do the same thing with the custom post-type's categories. Is there a way where I can search through the custom post-type and by category show different icons?
Ex: if (is_category('Case Studies') {return.......

I tried it that way, but it didn't work out. I think it has something to do with the custom post-type. Do I need to attach the custom post-type to the category somehow?

Comment: Update: There is also a custom post type attached to this category.

Comment: Please clearify your problem?

Comment: Ok. We have a portfolio with different categories. The portfolio is a custom post-type. We have a one portfolio category that we want to be more recognizable when someone views the whole portfolio (all categories). We want to just have a corner image stating that it's a case study. So the problem is I'm trying to do an if statement of: IF category = "Case Study" show this image in the top left corner of the thumbnail, else, don't show image. The problem is I don't know exactly how to make the if statement work. Do I need to use the category or use the taxomony? or both?

Comment: Stephen, [edit] the Question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for four custom post type categories and worked this out, I'm a PHP novice so this may not be the best way but it works for me.

Outside the loop.. I used 'single_term_title to get the name of the custom post type category and assigned it to a variable '$current_term', then used if / else if statements...

```
<?php $current_term = single_term_title("", false); 

//Cat name 1

if($current_term === 'Name 1') {
echo 'something';
} 

//Cat name 2
else if($current_term === 'Name 2') {
echo 'something';
}  

//Cat name 3
else if($current_term === 'Name 3') {
echo 'something';
} 

//Cat name 4
else if($current_term === 'Name 4') {
echo 'somehting';
}  

//Do nothing
else {
echo '';
}
?>
```